# Bitshifting on little-endian and big-endian

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, binary

Will this:

```
((0x10203040 >> 24) & 0xFF) == 0x10
```

always be TRUE on both little-endian and big-endian machines?

Comment: One thing that confuses many people is the fact that endian-ness is only related to *external storage*. Inside the processor's register, there is no "endian-ness". The number is read from the memory following the endian-ness conventions, but inside the register it is the same number, no matter of the initial endian-ness. So when right bit-shifting, you are simply getting rid of least significant bits, and there is no ambiguity.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. Endianness only affects how bytes are stored in memory. The value of `0x10203040` is always `270544960` regardless of whether it's the first or last byte in memory that is the `0x10`.

To gratuitously borrow images from the Wikipedia article on [Endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), regardless of which of these layouts our system uses:

[image][image]

the value of `0x0A0B0C0D` is still the same.

Answer (score 2):

> will this:
>
> ```
>  ((0x10203040 >> 24) & 0xFF) == 0x10
> ```
>
> be always TRUE on both little-endian and big-endian machines?

Yes, it will provide the same result on both architectures. It's actually a mathematical operation, and MSB LSB orders will be handled under the hood of that particular CPU's microcode.

Comment: Bitwise operations are mathematical operations? I don't think so...

Comment: @0x10203040 Why do you think boolean algebra and operations like bitshifting (which equivalents multiplying/dividing by 2 actually) aren't math?

Comment: You are right. I'm sorry.